# How useful is exchangeability for non-extendible sequences?

Tags: predictive-models, exchangeability

**Question**
How to model the predictive distribution $\mathrm{P}(X'\mid X_1=x_1, \dotsc, X_n=x_n)$ if I know that the sequence $X_1, \dotsc, X_n, X'$ is exchangeable, but I cannot assume it to be $N$-extendible for $N\gg n+1$, so that latent variables from de Finetti's theorem do not have to exist?

**More context**
Consider random variables $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ and $X'$. I have gathered the realizations $x_k$ of $X_k$ for $k\in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ into my training data set and I am trying to predict the unobserved realization of $X'$. In other words, I am interested in estimating the probability $\mathrm{P}(X'\mid X_1=x_1, \dotsc, X_n=x_n)$.

Assume that $X_1, \cdots, X_n, X'$ are i.i.d., so if $n$ is large, I can just use $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ to build an empirical distribution to approximate the distribution $\mathrm{P}(X')$. If $n$ is small, I will have to do some modelling – assume a reasonable parametric family of probability distributions $\{\mathrm{P}(\cdot; \theta) \mid \theta \in \Theta\}$ and then I fit $\theta$ to $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ in some manner (e.g., using penalized maximum likelihood estimates, ensemble methods or do Bayesian inference on $\theta$ and then build the predictive distribution by Bayesian model averaging or stacking).

All of this was possible due to the assumption that $X_1, \cdots, X_n, X'$ were i.i.d. **What would be a principled strategy knowing only that these variables were exchangeable?**

For example, consider $n\ge 9$ and an urn with 5 blue and 5 yellow balls drawn without replacement. The sequence $X_1, \cdots, X_n, X'$ is exchangeable, but not i.i.d. In particular, for $n=9$ I can perfectly guess the realization of $X'$ knowing the observed balls.

I know that the typical approach to modelling exchangeable data is still to assume existence of a latent variable $\theta$ such that conditioned on $\theta$ the observed variables are i.i.d., with often the motivation given by the de Finetti theorem applying to infinitely exchangeable sequences, which represents sequences as mixtures.
Bernardo and Smith (1994, Sec. 4.7) discuss a result of Diaconis and Freedman (1980) on finite exchangeable sequences showing that if the considered sequence can be extended to an exchangeable sequence of length $N$ with $N\gg n+1$, then the original sequence of length $n+1$ can be approximated very well with a mixture model. In the case of the urn model above, this assumption corresponds to having a larger urn with $N\gg n+1$ balls, so sampling without replacement does not matter too much and we are essentially i.i.d. sampling with replacement from an urn where only the ratio of yellow to blue balls matters. However, this approximation is not right for the considered scenario when the urn has only 10 balls and the original sequence cannot be extended.